# WP_Query - sort the results by meta value custom attribute wocoomerce

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic, meta-value

I’m trying to sort products by attribute value.

The attribute value is alphanumeric

[I started from this code](https://blog.robustastudio.com/e-commerce/sort-woocommerce-products-custom-attributes/)

Trying with the following code

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args');

function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
   global $wp_query;
       // Changed the $_SESSION to $_GET
   if (isset($_GET['orderby'])) {
       switch ($_GET['orderby']) :
           case 'pa_feat' :
               $args['order'] = 'ASC';
               $args['meta_key'] = 'pa_feat';
               $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
           break;
       endswitch;
   }
   return $args;
}
```

The values ​​are ordered as follows:

0,1 g
0,2 g
0,3 g
0,4 g
0,5 g
0,6 g
0,7 g
0,8 g
0,9 g
0,0 g
0,45 g

The value 0,0 g should be the first and 0,45 g should come after 0,4 g and before 0.5 g

i tried to edit

```
$args['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
```

with

```
$args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
$args['meta_type'] = 'NUMERIC'
```

or

```
$args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
$args['meta_type'] = 'DECIMAL'
```

but so the result is a completely wrong order.

I would like the correct ordering of attribute products to be:

0,0 g
0,1 g
0,2 g
0,3 g
0,4 g
0,45 g
0,5 g
0,6 g
0,7 g
0,8 g
0,9 g

Thanks in advance for your suggestions

Frank

Comment: Do you mean the numerical value representing 0.9 gramms ( `0.9` or is this the literal string `0,9g`? If so `0,9g` is not a numeric value and not a number/decimal/numeric

Comment: Also you're using an unusual plugin specific filter to modify the query, this isn't a place to get help with WooCommerce, WooCommerce and other 3rd party plugin/theme dev support is off topic and not in this stacks scope. You should ask via their official support routes or in their groups and communities.

Comment: Thanks @Tom J Nowell for your interest.

Yes, I wanted to use the value 0,9 g (0,9 grams), I also tried to use the values ​​0,9 or 0.9 (without g) but the result is always incorrectly sorted.

I understand that the topic is about a plugin but I thought that being a basic WP_Query orderby to metadata,

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters

someone could explain to me why the sorting is wrong.

Thanks again

Comment: because you're asking it to sort by a number, but it is not a number, don't store `0,9g`, store `0.9` and ensure all values are pure numeric values. Otherwise it'll be an alphanumeric sort aka 1,2,20,22,3,309,4,etc

Comment: I tried to change all values ​​to numerical 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 etc ... but the order is always wrong.
The products are sorted as follows: 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 0.0 0.45 etc ..
I still don't understand why the first value is not 0.0

Comment: it's possible this is because it's a WooCommerce filter, what you've done is correct for WordPress say if this were `pre_get_posts`, but you're using `woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args` which is a WooCommerce specific filter that may or may not have unknown additional consequences. Who knows what other functions are on that filter or what extra arguments it has. There may be a `meta_query` field!

Comment: Also, are you actually checking that those query vars are set or are you just looking at the end result and assuming they were set? Have you asked this in a WooCommerce community yet?

Comment: The official `WP_Query` doc has `meta_value_num` but if that doesn't work for you then you really need WooCommerce help, I can see no other issue with the query vars you're using, but this isn't a WordPress action, it's a WooCommerce action modifying WooCommerce functionality. You need WooCommerce help

Comment: Thanks @Tom J Nowell for the info, I'll try asking in the WooCommerce help